# Automatize repetitive process using a function applied for different variables and names in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataset like **original**

```
id <- c(1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4)
 period <- c(1,1,2,2,1,2,3,1,3)
 iso <- c("USA", "USA", "CHN", "ESP", "UK", "FRA", "KOR", "KOR", "ITA")
 via <- c(1, 1, 2, 7, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2)
 region <- c(4, 4, 4, 1, 27, 35, 9, 35, 35)
 
 original <- data.frame(id, period, iso, via, region)
```

and I want to generate a 1-row (by period) dataset with dummies for each main variable (iso, via, region -> in my dataset I have way more main variables). So the dummy-dataset for destination (iso) looks like **dest.dummies**:

```
dest.dummies <- original %>%
   select(id, period, iso) %>%
   filter(., iso != "") %>%
   distinct() %>%
   mutate(iso_=1)
 
 dest.dummies <- reshape(dest.dummies, idvar=c("id","period"), timevar="iso", direction="wide")
 dest.dummies[is.na(dest.dummies)==T] <- 0
 dest.dummies <- dest.dummies %>%
   dplyr::rename_all(
     funs(stringr::str_replace_all(., "iso_.", "iso_"))     #change pattern in names "iso_." by "iso_"
   )
```

My intention is to create a function such that I can substitute in the code above (dest.dummies)  the name "iso" by each of the **core** variables defined (**via, region, etc**).

I have tried to create a function() imputing the name of the variable in each case:

```
 dummyfier <- function(data, var){
   df <- data %>%
     select(id, period, {{var}}) %>%
     filter(., {{var}} != "") %>%
     distinct() %>%
     mutate('{{var}}_' :=1)
   
   df <- reshape(df, idvar=c("id","period"), timevar={{var}}, direction="wide")
df[is.na(df)==T] <- 0
   df <- df %>%
     dplyr::rename_all(
       funs(stringr::str_replace_all(., "var_.", "var_"))     #change pattern in names "var_." by "var_"
     )
 }

 dest.dummies <-  dummyfier(original, "iso")
 via.dummies <- dummyfier(original, "via")
 region.dummies <- dummyfier(original, "region")
```

but it does not make the trick.

Any idea on how to avoid this repetitive coding?
Thank you?

Comment: Welcome to the world of non-standard evaluation ([NSE](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have made some changes in the first 7 lines and the improvement is ok (see above). However, some new issues appear with the name of the variables. Line 8 doesn't execute properly (converts dataset into one 0...). Any comment is welcomed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your original attempt to :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

original %>%
  select(id, period, iso) %>%
  filter(iso != "") %>%
  distinct() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = iso, values_from = iso, 
              values_fn = length, values_fill = 0, names_prefix = 'iso_')

#     id period iso_USA iso_CHN iso_ESP iso_UK iso_FRA iso_KOR iso_ITA
#  <dbl>  <dbl>   <int>   <int>   <int>  <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
#1     1      1       1       0       0      0       0       0       0
#2     1      2       0       1       0      0       0       0       0
#3     2      2       0       0       1      0       0       0       0
#4     3      1       0       0       0      1       0       0       0
#5     3      2       0       0       0      0       1       0       0
#6     3      3       0       0       0      0       0       1       0
#7     4      1       0       0       0      0       0       1       0
#8     4      3       0       0       0      0       0       0       1
```

Now put that in a function :

```
dummyfier <- function(data, var) {
  col <- deparse(substitute(var))
  original %>%
    select(id, period, {{var}}) %>%
    filter({{var}} != "") %>%
    distinct() %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = {{var}}, values_from = {{var}}, 
                values_fn = length, values_fill = 0, 
                names_prefix = paste0(col, '_'))
}

dest.dummies <-  dummyfier(original, iso)
via.dummies <- dummyfier(original, via)
region.dummies <- dummyfier(original, region)
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak! Could you explain better the pivot_wider lines?

Comment: `names_from` is the column name from where the new column names would be given, `values_from` is column name from which the values of reshaped dataframe would come but since we are using `values_fn` here it will apply the function (`length`) to each value in `{{var}}`, `values_fill` is to fill the values to 0 instead of `NA` wherever a combination of names and value is not present. Finally, `names_prefix` will add a prefix to each column name. For `iso` it would be `iso_`, for `via` it would be `via_` etc.